# Error while using the write predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog-for-sharing

I was exploring the write predicate in Prolog but it behaves differently at times. I did go through [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220940/writing-predicate-in-prolog) but I am unable to spot the catch.

Predicate :

```
explore_write_predicate(InputList,Index):-
   TempIndex is Index+1,
   select(Element,InputList,TempList),
   write(TempIndex).
```

query:

```
explore_write_predicate([1,2,3,4],1).
```

Result :

```
2
true
```

The above code works fine but when I add one more argument to the write predicate(**Element**) it gives an error.

Predicate :

```
explore_write_predicate(InputList,Index):-
   TempIndex is Index+1,
   select(Element,InputList,TempList),
   write(TempIndex,Element).
```

query:

```
   explore_write_predicate([1,2,3,4],1).
```

Error:

```
No permission to call sandboxed `write(_1132,_1134)'
Reachable from:
      explore_write_predicate(A,B)
      swish_trace:swish_call(explore_write_predicate([1,2,3,4],1))
      '$swish wrapper'(explore_write_predicate([1,2,3,4],1),A)
```

Please help me why this anomaly.
P.S I also saw the documentation for write but could not get much out of it.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write only has an arity of 1. You need to call it as `write([TempIndex,Element])` to make it work.

Comment: or `write(TempIndex=Element)`

Comment: In any case: seriously consider to use `writeq` instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is two-fold:

Primarily, you appear to be using [SWISH](http://swish.swi-prolog.org/) as your interpreter of choice, which locks away a number of input/output methods (including [tab/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=tab/1), [write/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write/2), [get_single_char/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=get_single_char/1), [put/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=put/1), etc.), so you will be unable to use them.

Secondly, [write/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=write/2) requires a stream as its first argument, to which the second argument will be written - as mentioned in a comment, to write multiple things either pass the items as a list, or use multiple writes.